# Tub drain p trap angle

Tags: p-trap

Installing a new tub and needed to move the ptrap. Please let me know if the proposed angle poses any problems. [image]

Comment: Why does the joist with the hole look skinnier than the other joist? Am I hallucinating that? It looks substantially skinnier.

Comment: Off hand, it looks to be a 1" board put in as a patch after cutting out the joist there. On the other hand, there appears to be vinyl tile floor directly below the lumber, like this is a raised section over an old floor, so it may not really be a joist as such.

Answer (score 3):

**If** the *large vertical offset* to the drain is only for the picture, (because you have't cut that pipe to connect to, yet) this is fine - the P trap can be contorted in any way horizontally without changing its function.

But if there's a vertical drop of one pipe diameter (or somewhat less, depending on the applicable code) into the drain, that makes it an S trap, and those tend to siphon dry and give your tub sewer gas problems.

Using a sanitary Tee laid on its side rather than a Wye to enter the larger pipe is a pre-existing code violation.